# If I use my digital camera (w/min. ISO of 200) as a light meter, how do I set exposure for ISO 100 film?

Tags: exposure, iso, metering

I have a Fuji X-T100 and its lowest ISO setting is 200. Now, I’d like to shoot some slides like Provia 100 or Ektachrome 100 as well as Portra 160, using my Fuji as a light meter (it works pretty well for Portra 400 when I set the ISO  to 400 on my Fuji, and then adjust aperture and SS and use those settings on my analogue camera). What can I do? I don’t really wanna push those films to ISO 200...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "exposure triangle"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With the same camera settings, will a photo always be exposed correctly across different cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99387/with-the-same-camera-settings-will-a-photo-always-be-exposed-correctly-across-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISO100 needs double the amount of light as ISO200.  So you can either double the exposure time, or open the aperture one stop (a "stop" being a factor of 1.4, roughly, corresponding to doubling the aperture area).  You actually should practise thinking in stops since the recommendations of your digital camera will depend on the sensor size and stops it has available for its own purposes and does not take into account what analog camera you are working with.  The list of stops basically is f:1.4, f:2, f:2.8, f:4, f:5.6, f:8, f:11, f:16, f:22.  It's not likely you'll have to worry about f:1 ever, but f:1.2 (for some rather special fixed lenses) is half a stop down from f:1.4 and there are, obviously, other half-stops in between the full stop numbers.

So to map from ISO200 readings to ISO100 you can either
a) double exposure time
b) open the aperture one stop (which means going to a larger value of f:x and consequently a smaller value of x, the number part of the aperture specification, since f:x is a fraction)

If you want to use your Fuji for not only guessing the lighting but also the depth of field (you likely need to half-depress the shutter for that), you'll want comparable apertures, and those require actually plugging in the respective values of f.  The Fuji has about 24mm sensor width, a 35mm analog has 36mm, so you have comparable depth of field when the analog camera is about one stop slower than the digital camera for equal framing.

So if you are aiming for equal depth of field for half the ISO, you'll need to close down the analog camera one stop as compared to the digital camera's recommendation and expose 4 times as long.  Usually, you'll prefer exposing shorter and probably even opening *up* apertures which means that you'll have to watch your focus, its depth, and its effect on framing quite more than on the APS-C size sensor.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually aiming for landscape photography so shallow DOF is not really a factor!

Answer (score 6):

The Fuji X-T100 only has a limit of ISO 200 in Auto ISO. You can “Extend” or “Expand” the ISO to L which is 100 ISO.

Keep the camera in jpeg as it appears shooting RAW limits it to ISO 200.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the Extended ISO works more or less like this: the camera captures an image at its native ISO 200 and overexposes the RAW data by one exposure value (1 EV) in the process. Then, during the RAW conversion, it brings the exposure down again by 1 EV. So, not really ISO 100.

Comment: The OP is just using the X-T100 as an exposure meter. No images will be taken with the X-T100 so it doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 2):

An ISO 100 film is exactly half as sensitive as an ISO 200 film. It needs a shutter speed that is twice as long as that needed by the ISO 200 film.

Similarly, an ISO 160 film is exactly half as sensitive as an ISO 320 film. It needs a shutter speed that is twice as long as that needed by the ISO 320 film.

That's your answer.

That is... Meter using an ISO setting of 200 respectively 320. Double the shutter speed in your head.

Comment: The only thing I’d add to this is the caveat of shutter speeds getting into the seconds/minutes and reciprocity failure.

Comment: @Hueco not really sure what do you mean

Comment: So, if on ISO 200 it says 1/250, then on ISO 100 it'll be 1/125th, right?

Comment: @guest23749823749 [What is "reciprocity failure"?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/6900)

Comment: @guest23749823749 yes, your maths is spot on! Doubling 1/250 second gives a duration of 2/250 second. Which cancels down to 1/125 second.